# Let's see the Top Network Askers better

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, profile-picture

Noticed in my [MSE featured questions filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/80751/featured) that the avatars of the Top Network Askers are blurry.

Quick check showed it's because SE is requesting the 16x16 thumbnail, while having 30x30 size of the image itself, which cause the image to stretch.

Changing the requested image to 32x32 makes the avatars more clear, e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGCYr.jpg?s=16&g=1 vs https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGCYr.jpg?s=32&g=1

Live demo. Nick looks like this at the moment:

> [image]

Changing to  32x32 will make it much better:

> [image]

Comment: Seems gravatar URLs are correctly requested at 30x30 but imgur URLs are requested at 16x16

Comment: @Cai oh yeah, they have "s=" twice for Gravatar, and the second wins. So weird.